# $x'=\cos^5(x) +1$ has unique solution defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would appreciate if someone could please give me a hint on how to do this problem. Or where to see some examples. Unfortunately, the sources that I have do not seem to actually explain it and show some examples.

Given the IVP $x'=\cos^5(x) +1$, $x(0)=x_0$, show that this IVP has a unique solution for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should define $f(x,t)=\cos^5(x)+1$ and see if it satisfies Picard's criterion (namely, $f$ being continuous, Lipschitz etc..) If you want to follow some examples, here is a link that can help you.http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode5.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side is $C^1$ and so it is continuous and locally Lipschitz. Thus, any initial value problem has a unique solution, by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem (the original result by Picard had an additional assumption, and thus why one does not use universally "Picard theorem").

Moreover, in this case the derivative is bounded, and so the right-hand side is in fact Lipschitz (and not only locally Lipshitz). A simple application of Gronwall's lemma shows that all solutions are global (that is, are defined on the whole line).

Comment: Thank you. How does one apply Gronwall's lemma? I see in Wikipedia that it's something more advanced than I thought.

Comment: In this case it is easy: you get $|x(t)|=|x_0+\int_0^t(\cos^5x(s)+1)ds|\le |x_0|+2|t|$ and so the solution can't go to infinity in finite time. This implies that it is defined on the whole line.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm now getting to know how these things work actually :)